# Optional struct in Swift3

Tags: struct, swift3, option-type

I would like to declare a variable that stores an optional struct like so:

```
struct my_struct{
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
}

var my_variable = my_struct?
```

Am I right that this syntax was correct in Swift2? Unfortunately, it is not working in Swift3 anymore. What would be the "new" way to achieve this?

Comment: Note that it's Swift convention to use `UpperCamelCase` for type names, `lowerCamelCase` for everything else – don't use `snake_case`. I would highly recommend reading the [Optionals section of the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) – the declaration syntax is covered extensively there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax does not work in Swift 2 either.

First of all let's use a Swift compliant name

```
struct MyStruct { ... }
```

You have two options:

- `myVariable : MyStruct?` declares an optional struct without a value (`nil`)
- `myVariable : MyStruct?  = MyStruct()` declares an optional empty struct.

Note: Consider that you have to assign default values for the properties of the struct in the second form or use the memberwise initializer or write a custom initializer.

PS: Don't use optionals as a *don't-care* alibi. Swift encourages you to use non-optional types a much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct my_struct{
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
}

var my_variable:my_struct?
```

Note that types are usually capitalized and camel-cased by convention in Swift e.g.

```
struct MyStruct {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
}

var myVariable: MyStruct?
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!